# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly Error while compiling

Tags: java, cocoa, macos

I am developing an aplication in cocoa which uses some java classes .I am getting an error "JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly We cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin/java".I dont know how to resolve this..Please anyone help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 25):

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home` is exactly what you want to do.
```

In fact, all of the Apache projects (well, any project really) that hardcodes /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/... needs to use /usr/libexec/java_home if it exists. It's the only way you will know if Java is actually installed.

At some point in the future the symlinks in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/ will be going away, which will even more severely break these projects if they want to load using an Oracle/OpenJDK JVM.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Do you, by any chance, know why one can't use double/straight quotation marks?

Comment: Will this be persistent between restarts?

Answer (score 2):

Set `JAVA_HOME` to point to the `.../Home` directory, not the `java` binary. E.g.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
```

Why are you setting the environment variable in the first place? You shouldn't have to do this on OS X...

Comment: It is necessary, for example, when running ant build scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In your .bashrc file, add below lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to `~/.mavenrc` file

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Reference: [Maven ignoring JAVA_HOME on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026169/maven-ignoring-java-home-on-osx)

Answer (score 0):

Some times changing Java_HOME does not help, because in apache ant script the java_home is hardcoded.
    If when you change the JAVA_HOME still failed to run ant, you can try to change the default hardcode to your JAVA_HOME in ant script, like:

```
    $ vi /Users/apache-ant-1.8.3/bin/ant 
    #ant from line 83 to 93
    case "`uname`" in
      CYGWIN*) cygwin=true ;;
      Darwin*) darwin=true
               if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
 #delete JAVA_HOME=XXXXX(default line) , and give JAVA_HOME ur java home url       




JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home
                           fi
                           ;;
                  MINGW*) mingw=true ;;
                esac
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen because of the misconfigured `jenv`, in case it is installed.

In the `~/.bash_profile`, there should be these 3 lines:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
eval "$(jenv enable-plugin export)"
```

Then reload it by: `source ~/.bash_profile`