# Maven ignoring JAVA_HOME on OSX?

Tags: java, macos, maven

For some reason Maven is ignoring JAVA_HOME on OSX.

I recently upgraded from java 8 build 11 to java 8 build 25 and removed 11 because of a bug fix in 25.

I have updated `JAVA_HOME`:

```
:~ > echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

`java` and `javac` both report the correct version:

```
:~ > java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

:~ > javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25
```

`libexec` is correct:

```
:~ > /usr/libexec/java_home 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

the CurrentJDK symlink is correct:

```
:~ > ls -la /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
total 64
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel   374B Nov 19 14:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  wheel   408B Sep 23 14:29 ../
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    10B Jul 28 14:50 1.4@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    10B Jul 28 14:50 1.4.2@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    10B Jul 28 14:50 1.5@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    10B Jul 28 14:50 1.5.0@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    10B Jul 28 14:50 1.6@ -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    10B Jul 28 14:50 1.6.0@ -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   272B Jul 29 18:41 A/
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1B Jul 28 14:50 Current@ -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    58B Nov 19 14:35 CurrentJDK@ -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents
```

But Maven is still trying to hit 1.8.0_11:

```
:~ > mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Running OSX Mavericks.

Any idea why Maven is ignoring `JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A coworker told me what the problem was.  He didn't want the rep points so I'm just posting the answer for anybody who may find this via google.

The solution is to put

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
```

in

```
~/.mavenrc
```

Apparently for whatever reason maven gets its own profile file.  Creating the above file with the above value fixed the problem immediately:

```
:~ > mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T16:58:10-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: nice pretty useful info, this is only for maven3 correct?

Comment: I can't answer that as I've not run pre-maven3 on mac

Comment: Fixed this issue on mac sierra with maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this issue by adding

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"`

to

`~/.mavenrc`

Apple recommends using `/usr/libexec/java_home` instead of using the whole path to Java

Comment: I cannot find `~/.mavenrc`. Do I have to create it?

Comment: if it's not there then yes, create it.