# maven ignoring jenv settings

Tags: java, macos, maven, jenv

I had OSX with `Java 1.6` installed, and I just installed `jenv` along with `Java 1.7`:

```
$ jenv local '1.7'
$ jenv versions
  system
  1.6
  1.6.0.65
* 1.7 (set by /Users/me/workspace/.java-version)
  1.7.0.79
  oracle64-1.6.0.65
  oracle64-1.7.0.79
```

`jenv` is doing its job, with `$ java -version` always working, showing 1.6 when I've set it to 1.6, and 1.7 when I've set it to 1.7:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"                    <--------------------------------- YAY!!
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

**... but maven is ignoring my settings:**

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.2 (r1056850; 2011-01-08 19:58:10-0500)
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc. <--------------------------------- BAH!!
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026169/maven-ignoring-java-home-on-osx) where the guy just needed to hardcode his `JAVA_HOME` inside `.mavenrc`, but I don't want mine hard-coded (thus `jenv`!), and I don't have a `~/.mavenrc`, nor an `/etc/mavenrc`.

The version it's using seems to be from whatever's first on the `/usr/libexec/java_home` output, so in the short term I was able to get 1.6 back again by tweaking 1.7's `Info.plist` file (from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994919/145499)), but that just means I get 1.6 instead of 1.7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You need to install the jenv maven plugin, try the following command and reload your shell:

> jenv enable-plugin maven

Comment: Not sure why it took me so long to notice this answer. This works like a charm! Much better than having to prefix everything. Thanks (even if belatedly)!

Comment: Thank you, @tenfourty! This really helped. This worked for me when switching between different versions of Java for building projects with multiple JDKs for testing.

Comment: I did have this enabled but it didn’t work. Turns out, jenv (as installed by Homebrew) uses a symlink in ~/.jenv/plugins and this pointed to an old jenv version. Fixed the link, fixed jenx, fixed Maven!

Comment: I needed to run jenv exec mvn -version. Only enabling the plugin didn't work for me.

Comment: I had issues after a Homebrew (macOS) upgrade today where Maven wasn't respecting the configured JVM version. Not sure if a rehash and shell reload would have taken care of it, but disabling and reenabling the Maven plugin fixed it for sure.

Comment: Setting up a new machine today I ran into an issue where `jenv enable-plugin` resulted in `no such command`. Addressed by running `jenv doctor` and resolving the issues found as suggested by https://github.com/jenv/jenv/issues/64#issuecomment-64396967

Comment: This fixed my problem a few months ago, but now i ran into the same problem again without having changed anything. Maven was ignoring jenv even though the maven plugin was activated in jenv. Disabling and re-enabling didn't help either.

I also had to enable the export plugin to fix it this time: `jenv enable-plugin export`

Answer (score 33):

I had a similar problem. I got things running by prefixing all command with `jenv exec`:

```
jenv exec mvn -version
```

Comment: Awesome! I think i'll `alias` it this way. Thanks!

Comment: This answer worked for my when the project was using __mvnw__ wrapper

Answer (score 19):

Now, there's a new option how to set JAVA_HOME via jenv export plugin:

```
jenv enable-plugin export
```

See https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv/issues/44#issuecomment-233124185

Answer (score 6):

If you have enabled the `maven` and `export` plugins, and still have problems, check that you don't have a `~/.mavenrc` file which is setting `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding further, I deleted the ~/.mavenrc and everything works as expected!

Answer (score 2):

If `jenv enable-plugin export` still doesn't work then you should restart the Terminal and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use `pwsh` on OS X and was able to get it working with the `maven` and `export` plugins enabled.

However, I encountered the following gotchas:

- Run `sh-enable-plugin` instead of `enable-plugin` when enabling maven and export (`enable-plugin` produces a "command not found" error).
- Edit the `mvn` script (`code "$(which mvn)"`) and remove the `JAVA_HOME=` bit so that you end up with something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec/bin/mvn"  "$@"
```

These additional steps fixed my issues so that `mvn -v` prints the correct JDK version.