# mvn -version on command line showing different version of Java

Tags: java, maven, installation

I played around with jenv today, to setup Java 1.8 as global version and 1.7 for one project locally. Since then mvn command in the global locations is showing java version 12 -

```
SandeepanNath:current sandeepan.nath$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/sandeepan.nath/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
Java version: 12.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Whereas Java version is showing as expected -

```
SandeepanNath:.ssh sandeepan.nath$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

I tried uninstalling and installing maven via sdkman again, on Mac. Although it did not download it fresh. I am still getting the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: are you on linux or windows? Could you please execute echo $JAVA_HOME

Comment: There is a version of java 12 on your machine according to your output. The maven is configured to use that java version. You can change it in maven config file

Comment: @tashkhisi if you read the penultimate paragraph, you will see OP is on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably your answer might already be here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7033062/4424668

I guess, you have set up a JAVA_HOME environment variable at some point, which points to a Java 12-Installation.

What might actually be the solution to your specific problem (Jenv + Maven) is written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37466252/4424668

You might need to enable the maven Plugin for Jenv by calling `jenv enable-plugin maven`. Afterwards, Maven should consider the version activated by Jenv.

Edit:
Since you actually use SDKMAN für managing maven candidates, you might consider using SDKMAN for Java Candidates as well. Anyhow, maybe the maven plugin does not actually fix your SDKMAN maven candidates. An even easier solution may be to enable the export-plugin instead, which actually sets the Environment Variable directly. Have a look about that on the Github-Page of Jenv: https://github.com/jenv/jenv