# Installation of Galago fails: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, unix, lemur

I am trying to install Galago via the binary file(galago-3.12-bin) on unix. When i run the file I get the following error:

> SEF-IS-017660:galago-3.12-bin anton$ bin/galago Error: JAVA_HOME is
>   not defined correctly.   We cannot execute
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java

When I check my java home directory I get:

> SEF-IS-017660:galago-3.12-bin anton$ echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home

How can I correct the problem?  The install is expecting a certain home directory but mine is different?

Answer (score 1):

I could use the same answer as that provided in [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145705/java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-error-while-compiling)

> export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

Fixed the problem